# Android double buffering

Tags: android

Is double buffering makes any sense on android? Can it be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean graphics?  Double buffering completely makes sense for graphics.

On android, the surface and canvas interfaces support double buffering, and the facility is used extensively.